# Does PHP Eclipse Internal Browser usually have CSS issues?

Tags: php, eclipse, browser, internal

I was trying out the PHP Eclipse Internal Browser.

I set the Internal Browser to the Chrome Web Browser.

**My Steps:**
 Clicked Windows > Web Browser > Chrome (the other options of course were default, IE, FF)

However viewing a web page in the External Chrome Browser rendered differently when viewed in the PHP Eclipse Internal Browser(Set To Chrome).

**In comparing internal PHP Eclipse browser set to Chrome with external Chrome Browser:**

- Negative Margins showed differently
- Text Line heights showed differently

I thought that the presentation would be the same on the Internal and External Browser.

I changed the PHP Eclipse Internal Browser to use IE and Fire Fox and same problem occurred.

The presentation of webpages in internal PHP Eclipse browser does not seem to change despite changing the web browser it is to use.

Is this a common problem? And is there a fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I prefer do not use the internal browser of (in my case easyPhpEclipse), cause it uses the IE browser as default. 
Since eclipse is a opensource IDE, you can look around inside the code to understand better the functions of the internal browser.

But I really don't recommend you to use the internal browser, first, you have no Tabs, second, no options at all. It's a very simple functions of a browser.

Good Luck!

Comment: Thanks. I guess external browser would be my fix for now.

Comment: @DaGambit No, he wants you to study the source code of the internal browser until you fully understand it. That's not unreasonable...